# Modifying a HY-DIV268N stepper motor driver

Tags: microcontroller, stepper-driver

Drivers from the family HY-DIV268N-xA have these dumb switches that regulate the step. I'd like to use a microcontroller for that. Does anyone know if they can be modified to maybe replace them with MOSFETs or directly use the uC's pins?

Comment: There are other models of stepper driver that use mosfets and microcontrollers - usually for only a few dollars more. These are usually the microstepping ones.

Comment: Yes, but few of those are rated for high current. I already found one in a good price, but that was luck